# What does it mean that the product of two vectors produces real number?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am going over inner product space.

I know that linear space has an inner product as long as it satisfies $4$ conditions.

And, the book says that for $x,y$ in $V$, there is a real number corresponding $(x,y)$

> What does that mean?

For $\mathbb R^2$, where $x=(x_1,x_2)$, $y=(y_1,y_2)$, what is inner product of $(x,y)$, would it be $x_1y_1+x_2y_2$?

Comment: Yes, it is $x_1 \cdot y_1+x_2 \cdot y_2$!!

Comment: but there is other way to define it such as 2x1y1+x1y2+y1x2+x2y2   what is the diffrence?

Comment: $<x,y>$ is an inner product on $R^n$ iff $<x,y>=x^TAy$, where $A$ is is a symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues are strictly positive. $$$$
There are inner products on $R^n$ that are not the usual
dot product $x · y = x_1y_1 + · · · + x_ny_n$, e.g. in this case.